# Run Cron job with local php.ini file - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, task

I have created a cron job with Laravel. The problem is I am using `file_get_contents` in it and when I run the job, there is an error:

> file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

I know that in the command I need to specify and the local php.ini file, where `allow_url_open` is enabled.

I am using shared hosting, where in global `php.ini` file this property is disabled, but in my local is enabled. When I run the job it uses global `php.ini`.

I am running the job in `SSH`: - `php artisan my_command`.
I need to run it and manually in the code, too, like:

```
Artisan::call('my_command');
```

I have created the command with:

```
php artisan make:command MyCommand
```

Then in `handle` method, I am using `file_get_contents`.

How to speecify the `php.ini` file when I run a Task with Laravel 5.8 ?

EDIT:
On the hosting, this option is enabled and I can use it in my code.
If I run `phpinfo()`, I see that is enabled, too, because, it is used local `php.ini`.

Comment: THat is only changable in php.ini and if you are on a shared host they probably wont allow you to change the php.ini

Comment: They have an option to change it, and it is enabled, if I access an action with `file_get_contents`, it works `phpinfo()` says that it is enabled, too. It is disabled global !

Comment: There may be 2 seperate `php.ini files. One for Apache/PHP and one for CLI/PHP

Comment: They said ,that, there is global and local `php.ini`, I need to use local in my command, but I don't know, where and how to specify that.

Comment: I know, where they are, I don't know, where to add them.

Comment: I must add them, somewhere in the code, this is what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

The solution wasto make an alias to my `php.ini` file.
This file is located in:

`/home/<USERNAME>/php73-fcgi.ini`

Global `php.ini` file location:

`/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/php`

The command that I have executed in `SSH`:

```
alias php='/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/php -c /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/php -c /home/<USERNAME>/php73-fcgi.ini'
```

`73` is the version of `PHP`.